# Auto-reload page when Webpack chunks are outdated

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading

I have an app bundled with Webpack.

There is a main bundle file and the rest of the code is split into chunks per screen. Both the main bundle and chunks are generated with a hash as part of the file name.

```
...
filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
chunkFilename: '[id].[name]-[hash].js'
...
```

After deploying new changes to production the bundle and chunk files are replaced (so, old ones are removed).

If a user has the app open and tries to navigate to a page that is supposed to load an outdated chunk, part of the application crashes.

The question: **Is there a way to detect failure to load a chunk and auto reload the screen or present an appropriate message?**

What kind of strategy is advisable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [runtime chunks](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk) so that each entry chunk does not embed a runtime. This should translate to being able to "plug-and-play" chunks in production.

Answer (score 0):

Usually failure to load a part of the chunk is either due to server issues or network issues, or browser issues... so it's worth cross-checking if there are some type of incompatibilities (in specific browsers or browser plugin), poor server performance, etc. That said, there's a [webpack plugin to auto retry loading chunks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-retry-chunk-load-plugin),

If you are specifically trying to have a component loaded lazily from an external/unreliable source you can also use something like:

```
export default function componentLoader(lazyComponent, attemptsLeft) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    lazyComponent()
      .then(resolve)
      .catch((error) => {
        // let us retry after 1500 ms
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (attemptsLeft === 1) {
            reject(error);
            return;
          }
          componentLoader(lazyComponent, attemptsLeft - 1).then(resolve, reject);
        }, 1500);
      });
  });
}
```

See the [full gist here](https://gist.github.com/Botfather/4cfc9c7ba363c892acced7cc44d9f7ff#file-componentloader-js).